# How to obtain the PK of a new element I just inserted in the database using MYSQLADAPTER.UPDATE

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I want to know how to get the "auto-generated" primary key of the new element I just inserted in the database. I'm getting this error **"Concurrency violation: the DeleteCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records"**. I believe that it is because the dataSet does not have the primary key of the new element.

PD> I only get this error when I working with new elements. Also, I'm using C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you insert into the database you can return the SCOPE_IDENTITY of the inserted record via an OUTPUT parameter.  From there can update your dataSet with the returned value.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert]

    @Name VARCHAR(255),
    @Email VARCHAR(255),
    @ID INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable([Name], Email)
    VALUES (@Name,@Email)
    SET @ID = CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT)
END
```